# Jira Mail Handler dosent create issues for user

Tags: jira

i have a problem with the jira mail handler. If a non existing user send a mail to support@xxxx.com the mail handler creates a new issue und creates a user in jira witch syncs to a specific ldap directory.

If a existing user send a mail to the support@xxxx.com jira create a issue. The Problem is for some existing user jira dosnt create a issue and i have no idea why. But the mail is marked as read.

I can't find nothing unusual in the jira-database and in the logfile. (jira debug is enabled)

Jira log:

> 2015-03-18 13:16:00,237 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * OK Gimap ready for requests from 91.118.111.246 e17mb107777603wen
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,237 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A0 CAPABILITY
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,267 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDR
>   EN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
>   A0 OK Thats all she wrote! e17mb107777603wen
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,267 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,271 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar
>   f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=support-grag@xxxx.com, password=
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,271 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,552 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK support-grag@xxxxx.com authenticated (Success)
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,553 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A2 CAPABILITY
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,679 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
>   A2 OK Success
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,679 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [servicedesk.squalor.email.SDMessageProcessor] Connection to Mail Server established successfully
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,680 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,680 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A3 SELECT INBOX
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,718 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343008x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 / [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request / and user ANON
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,723 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343009x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa and user ANON
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,727 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343009x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa [atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKiller] Lowering session inactivity timeout to 60
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,732 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/Dashboard.jspa and user ANON
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,736 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [atlassia
>   n.analytics.client.EventTracer] Processing event class com.atlassian.jira.event.DashboardViewEvent from com.atlassian.event.internal.EventPublisherImpl.publish(EventPublisherImpl.java:79) com.atlassian.jira.web.action.Dashboard.doExecute(Dashboard.java:191) webwork.action.ActionSupport.execute(ActionSupport.java:165) com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:88) webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:39) webwork.interceptor.NestedInterceptorChain.proceed(NestedInterceptorChain.java:31) webwork.interceptor.ChainedInterceptor.intercept(ChainedInterceptor.java:16) webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:35) webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:225) webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:154)
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,736 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.extractor.JiraPropertyExtractor] Extracting property id
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,737 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.extractor.JiraPropertyExtractor] Extracting property params
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,737 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.listener.ProductEventListener] Sending event message dashboardview took 1099 ?s
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,739 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/views/dashboard.jsp and user ANON
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadge:
>   Class()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity
>   .htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity
>   .htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayableUrl
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getDisplayableUrl()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLabel
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLabel com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLabel()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayableLabel
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLabel.getDisplayableLabel()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDashboardId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.TabImpl.getDashboardId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboar
>   d.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: isWritable
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public boolean com.atlassian.gadgets.view.View.isWritable()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName()
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: []
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKiller] Upping session inactivity timeout to 18000
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,807 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,807 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,808 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,808 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check
>   2015-03-18 13:16:00,812 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner    Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing)
>   * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing *)] Flags permitted.

I had no idea, please help me.

Comment: You need to do something about that log. Format it as code, for example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JSbLN3sg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fail

```
2015-03-18 13:16:00,237 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * OK Gimap ready for requests from 91.118.111.246 e17mb107777603wen 2015-03-18 13:16:00,237 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A0 CAPABILITY 2015-03-18 13:16:00,267 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDR EN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN A0 OK Thats all she wrote! e17mb107777603wen 2015-03-18 13:16:00,267 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH 2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2 2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN 2015-03-18 13:16:00,268 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN 2015-03-18 13:16:00,271 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Dar f nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap.gmail.com, user=support-grag@xxxx.com, password= 2015-03-18 13:16:00,271 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed 2015-03-18 13:16:00,552 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK support-grag@xxxxx.com authenticated (Success) 2015-03-18 13:16:00,553 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A2 CAPABILITY 2015-03-18 13:16:00,679 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT A2 OK Success 2015-03-18 13:16:00,679 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [servicedesk.squalor.email.SDMessageProcessor] Connection to Mail Server established successfully 2015-03-18 13:16:00,680 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1 2015-03-18 13:16:00,680 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] A3 SELECT INBOX 2015-03-18 13:16:00,718 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343008x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 / [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request / and user ANON 2015-03-18 13:16:00,723 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343009x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa and user ANON 2015-03-18 13:16:00,727 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343009x1 - 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/MyJiraHome.jspa [atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKiller] Lowering session inactivity timeout to 60 2015-03-18 13:16:00,732 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/Dashboard.jspa and user ANON 2015-03-18 13:16:00,736 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [atlassia n.analytics.client.EventTracer] Processing event class com.atlassian.jira.event.DashboardViewEvent from com.atlassian.event.internal.EventPublisherImpl.publish(EventPublisherImpl.java:79) com.atlassian.jira.web.action.Dashboard.doExecute(Dashboard.java:191) webwork.action.ActionSupport.execute(ActionSupport.java:165) com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:88) webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:39) webwork.interceptor.NestedInterceptorChain.proceed(NestedInterceptorChain.java:31) webwork.interceptor.ChainedInterceptor.intercept(ChainedInterceptor.java:16) webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:35) webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:225) webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:154) 2015-03-18 13:16:00,736 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.extractor.JiraPropertyExtractor] Extracting property id 2015-03-18 13:16:00,737 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.extractor.JiraPropertyExtractor] Extracting property params 2015-03-18 13:16:00,737 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [analytics.client.listener.ProductEventListener] Sending event message dashboardview took 1099 ?s 2015-03-18 13:16:00,739 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [internal.user.external.ExternalCustomerAccessService] Anonymous is true for request /secure/views/dashboard.jsp and user ANON 2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,742 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName 2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,743 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName 2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,744 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,747 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,748 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,750 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadge: Class() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity .htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity .htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,751 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getStyleClass 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getStyleClass() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLink 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLink() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,752 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayableUrl 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLink.getDisplayableUrl() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getLabel 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLabel com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$WebItem.getLabel() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayableLabel 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public java.lang.String com.atlassian.gadgets.util.WebItemFinder$GadgetWebLabel.getDisplayableLabel() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,753 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDashboardId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.internal.impl.TabImpl.getDashboardId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getId 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard.DashboardId com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboar d.internal.impl.DashboardImpl.getId() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,754 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: isWritable 2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public boolean com.atlassian.gadgets.view.View.isWritable() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,760 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Getting introspector method for getter: getDisplayName 2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] got method: public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2630.getDisplayName() 2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [velocity.htmlsafe.introspection.AnnotationBoxingUberspect] Got return annotations: [] 2015-03-18 13:16:00,762 http-bio-8011-exec-24 DEBUG anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKiller] Upping session inactivity timeout to 18000 2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,798 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,807 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,807 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,808 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,808 http-bio-8011-exec-24 INFO anonymous 796x343010x1 18zam0p 85.126.241.58,91.118.111.246 /secure/Dashboard.jspa [servicedesk.internal.user.SDUserFactoryImpl] Could not find a logged in user in context when performing a permission check 2015-03-18 13:16:00,812 atlassian-scheduler-quartz1.clustered_Worker-2 DEBUG ServiceRunner Von JIRA Service Desk verwendeter Mailhandler. Darf nicht ge?ndert oder gel?scht werden. 10.111 [com.atlassian.mail.incoming] * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing) * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $NotPhishing *)] Flags permitted.
```

Comment: I solve my Problem, i found in the db more user with the same email address. After change it works for me. Thank you!